# Trivial Orthogonal Complement $\implies$ Denseness!

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

*Disclaimer: Though I don't need it anymore this is interesting in its own!*

Is it true that if the orthogonal complement is trivial then the subset was dense:
$$A^\bot=\{0\}\implies\overline{A}=X$$
Moreover does it hold that a dense subset remains dense in the completion:
$$\overline{A}^X=X\implies\overline{A}^{\hat{X}}=\hat{X}$$
Of course the converses are both trivial and I suppose both fail in general. Besides for complete a.k.a. Hilbert spaces the first is just a consequence of the orthogonal decomposition for closed subspaces.

Comment: What does $\perp$ mean in your question?

Comment: By the way, your recent edit makes nonsense out of Vladimir's answer. This is very rude to him. You should have asked a new question instead.

Comment: It is meant 'being orthogonal' within the direct sum of Hilbert spaces: $(x_0,Ax_0)\perp(x,A\restriction_\mathcal{D} x):\iff \langle x_0,x\rangle_X+\langle Ax_0,A\restriction_\mathcal{D}x\rangle_Y=0$

Comment: Better look from this site: If $A$ is closed then $\mathcal{G}(A)$ closed in $X\times Y$ so also complete. Then $\mathcal{G}(A)=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})}\oplus\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})^\perp$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{G}(A)$. Now if $\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})^\perp=\{0\}$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{G}(A)$ then $\mathcal{G}(A)=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A\restriction_\mathcal{D})}$ so $\mathcal{D}$ was a core. The condition written out is what I mentioned in the question...

Comment: @Vladimir: Do u want me to open a new question rather? I mean the former question is interesting in its own so I wouldn't mind opening a new thread rather...

Comment: Yes if you wish open a new thread. But pretty much the answer will be the same; for a countrerexample, just take D to be the identity operator $L^2\to L^2$ on the domain $A$; then $A$ is not a core but if we consider the operator in $C_0^\infty$ then in the graph of the identity operator there will be no vector orthogonal to the graph of D restricted to $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is of course true. If $A$ is dense in $X$, then it is also dense in $\hat X$. Just approximate $x\in\hat X$ by $x_n\in X$, $||x-x_n||\le 2^{-n}$ and then approximate each $x_n$ by $y_n\in A$,  $||y_n-x_n||\le 2^{-n}$.

The first is false: let $X=C_0^\infty(R)$, $\hat X=L^2(R)$, and $A=\{f\in X|\int_a^bf(x)dx=0\}$. Then $A^\perp=\{0\}$ in $X$, because $1_{[a,b]}\notin X$, but $A$ is clearly not dense.

Comment: Ok good - you don't mind if I still specify my question more?

Comment: I take "Ok, good" for "Thank you." You are welcome. Shoot.

Comment: Oh yes ^^ I meant: Thank you!!!