# When does a trivial orthogonal complement imply the subset is dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

Let $A \subset X$.

When do we have
$A^\bot=\{0\}\implies\overline{A}=X  \ \ \ \ ?$

I've read some answers in the forum that stated that for the converse $A$ had to be a subspace of $X$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831897/trivial-orthogonal-complement-implies-denseness

Comment: A trivial situation: $A=[-1,1]\subseteq X=\mathbb R$.