# Understanding the proof that a trivial orthogonal complement does not imply density of a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

In this post: [Trivial Orthogonal Complement $\implies$ Denseness!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831897/trivial-orthogonal-complement-implies-denseness) the relationship between trivial orthogonal complement and density of a subspace is investigated. The accepted answer:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/831907/877219 shows that trivial orthogonal complement does not imply density of the subspace. Namely, we take $X = C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}), \hat{X} = L^2(\mathbb{R}), A = \{f\in X\mid \int_a^bf(x)dx = 0\}$. Then the accepted answer states that:

> $A^\perp = \{0\}$ since $1_{[a,b]}\not\in X$, but $A$ is clearly not dense.

I don't quite understand why this shows that $A^\perp = \{0\}$. Could you explain to me in detail the gist of this proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the indicator function ${\bf 1}_{[a,b]}$ of $[a,b]$, so $A^\perp$ is the span of ${\bf 1}_{[a,b]}$. But the latter intersects $X$ only in the zero function because ${\bf 1}_{[a,b]}$ is not smooth (continuous).

The details read as follows: Let $X:=(C_0^\infty(\mathbb R),\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{L^2})$ and $A:=\{g\in X:\int_a^bg(x)dx=0\}$. Note that $A$ can be re-written as
\begin{align*}
A&=\Big\{g\in X:\int_{\mathbb R}{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}g(x)dx=0\Big\}\\
&=\{g\in X:\langle{\bf 1}_{[a,b]},g\rangle_{L^2}=0\}\\
&=\{g\in L^2(\mathbb R):\langle{\bf 1}_{[a,b]},g\rangle_{L^2}=0\}\cap X=\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2}\cap X\,.
\end{align*}
where $(\cdot)^{\perp,L^2}$ is the orthogonal complement **in** $\bf L^2$.

Now we want to show that the orthogonal complement of $A$ **in** $\bf X$ (i.e. $A^\perp=A^{\perp,L^2}\cap X$) is just the zero function.
For this we need the following facts (in this order):

- The orthogonal complement of any non-trivial set $A$ equals the orthogonal complement of $\overline{A}$ (follows from Cauchy-Schwarz)
- Using that [$X$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552983/proving-that-the-smooth-compactly-supported-functions-are-dense-in-l2) one readily verifies that $\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2}\cap X$ is dense in $\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2}$.
- Given any non-empty subset $A$ of a Hilbert space one has [$(A^\perp)^\perp=\overline{\operatorname{span}(A)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043940/double-orthogonal-complement-is-equal-to-topological-closure)

With these tools at hand we compute
\begin{align*}
A^\perp=A^{\perp,L^2}\cap X&=(\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2}\cap X)^{\perp,L^2}\cap X\\
&=\big(\overline{\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2}\cap X}\big)^{\perp,L^2}\cap X\\
&=(\{{\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\}^{\perp,L^2})^{\perp,L^2}\cap X\\
&=\operatorname{span}({\bf 1}_{[a,b]})\cap X=\{0\}
\end{align*}
so altogether $A^\perp=\{0\}$. The last step is where we used that ${\bf 1}_{[a,b]}\not\in X$.

Comment: @Frederick vom Ende : Does your answer contradict the answer to the fourth question on page 15 of the document at this link below.  I didn't understand it but maybe it's not correct. Thank you for any clarification. It's much appreciated.  https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2021/REUPapers/Adler.pdf

Comment: In Hilbert spaces—that is, *complete* inner product spaces—a subspace being dense is equivalent to its orthogonal complement being zero; this is what is written in the document you linked, and this is a correct statement. The point of this question was to clarify to which extent completeness is necessary for this to hold. The example given above shows that in **general** (i.e. non-complete) inner product spaces—such as $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$—subspaces can have trivial orthogonal complement without being dense.

Comment: aaaah. okay. I get it now ( not the adler proof but the lack of contradiction ). It's much appreciated.  You explained your Feb 19 answer so beautifully that even I could follow it. Thank you.